# Display the first content element (mask element) of a page in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-10.x

Is it possible to display the first content element (mask element) of a page in a menu in TYPO3 10.x?

Answer (score 0):

In general: yes.

Depending on your way to build the menu (pure typoscript or menu-processor and FLUID) the solutions are less or more complicated as there is no immediate access to that CE.

While generating the link to that menu entry you have access to the page id. With that id you can build a select to get the first CE (in the main column?) and render it.

In typoscript you would use a `tt_content` object, in FLUID you would  use a viewhelper.